# why is match undefined in fetch function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, react-hooks

I'm using match to pull an ID that will search an API for that ID and pull data from it. This was working until I started moving my files around and now I'm not sure how to pass match into my fetch function

HeroDetail.services

```
import React from 'react'

export const fetchHeroDetail = async ({match}) => {
    const data = await fetch(`https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats`)
    const item = await data.json()
    const heroId = match.params.id
    console.log(match.params.id)
    const hero = item.find(element => element.id === Number(heroId))
    console.log(hero)
    return await hero

};
```

HeroDetail Component

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import "../App.css"
import {fetchHeroDetail} from './services/HeroDetail.services'

const setHeroDetail = async setHero => {
     const hero = await fetchHeroDetail()
    setHero(hero)
}

function HeroDetail() {

    const [hero, setHero] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
            setHeroDetail(setHero)
    },[])




    return(
        <div>
           <h1>{hero.localized_name} </h1>
            <h2>{hero.move_speed}</h2>
            <h2>{hero.base_health}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default HeroDetail
```

Comment: Where are you defining `match`?  Why aren't you passing it in `fetchHeroDetail()`?

Comment: _"why is match undefined"_ - Because; `fetchHeroDetail = async ({match}) => {...}` but `fetchHeroDetail()`

Comment: @jmargolisvt I'm defining it because match.params.id is the ID in the URL that i'm fetching for.

Comment: I think the question was **where are you defining it**. It was asked because the function fetchHeroDetail is expecting an argument that you never give it when you call it. Nor does the HeroDetail component have any code that would indicate the parameter could be in props passed.

Answer (score 1):

You should just do this:

```
function HeroDetail() {

    const [hero, setHero] = useState({})

    useEffect(async () => {
         if (!hero) {
          const data = await fetchHeroDetail()
          setHero(data)
         }
    })
...
}
```